# Time complexity of pop with an argument in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

EDIT: This is a duplicate question, but I had trouble understanding the wiki page despite reading the accepted answer there. I just added an answer to that question, which also covers the time complexity for the average case and amortized worst case scenario.

This [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) says that when you pass in an argument to a list's pop method that its worst case time complexity is O(k) with k referring to the number passed in for k or the number of elements in k.

However, if say I pop the 3rd index of a list of 11 elements wouldn't everything after the 3rd element of the list have to be re-adjusted making the average time complexity O(n-k) And since you could remove the first element of a list wouldn't the worst case time complexity be O(n)?

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
list2 = list1
print(list1[3]) # d
list1.pop(3)
print(list1) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
print(list1[3]) # e
print(id(list1) == id(list2)) # True (They're still the same item in memory)
```

Is there some unique way Python implements lists under the hood that I'm not understanding? Or is the wiki wrong?

Comment: In the average and worst cases, O(k) is the same as O(n) as they differ at most by a constant factor.

Comment: @DYZ What do you mean by that?

Comment: Removing items towards the front of the list *will* be slower than removing items at the end, you're correct -- however, the *average* is still in O(*k*).  If you assume that removing the (*k*-1)th element takes 0 shift operations, the (*k*-2)th element takes 1 shift operations, ..., then the first element takes *k*-1 operations to remove.  The average over all of these is still in O(*k*).  Note that first line of the section: "The Average Case assumes parameters generated uniformly at random."

Comment: In brief: There is no difference between O(k) and O(n).